# What is wrong with the following program code, attempting to initialize a 4 x 4 matrix of integers?

Tags: python, list

What is wrong with the following program code, attempting to initialize a 4 x 4 matrix of integers? How should the initialization be done?

```
line = [0] * 4
matrix = [line, line, line, line]
```

Comment: Wrong in what sense? This results in a list of lists (or a "matrix" if you will). What do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> line = [[0]*4 for _ in xrange(4)]
>>> line
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Don't do this though:

```
>>> line = [[0]*4]*4
>>> line
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The output looks same, but the problem here is all inner lists are actually the same object repeated 4 times:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in line]
[156931756, 156931756, 156931756, 156931756]
```

So, changing one of them is going to affect all:

```
>>> line[2][0] = 10
>>> line
[[10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]]
```

---

Same thing is applicable to your code:

```
>>> line = [0] * 4
>>> matrix = [line, line, line, line]
>>> [id(x) for x in matrix]
[158521804, 158521804, 158521804, 158521804]
```

If `line` contains only immutable object then you can change your code do:

```
>>> matrix = [line[:] for _ in xrange(4)]
```

But, if `line` contains mutable objects itself, then you'd have to use either `copy.deepcopy` or better create a new `line` object inside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

you could use numpy for that if you want to perform computations on your matrix

```
import numpy as np

zeros = np.zeros([4,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
>>> line = [0] * 4
>>> matrix = [line, line, line, line]
>>> matrix[0][0] = 5
>>> matrix
[[5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You have and array of references to the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong here that you create a *list* of 4 references to *line* list. If you change any of sub-lists or *line* itself, you affect all sub-lists of matrix, since they (sub-lists) are essentially the same list
Here is a little demonstration

```
In [108]: line = [0] * 4

In [109]: matrix = [line, line, line, line]

In [110]: line[1]=2

In [111]: matrix
Out[111]: [[0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0]]

In [112]: matrix[1][3] = 4

In [113]: matrix
Out[113]: [[0, 2, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 4]]

In [114]: for row in matrix:
       .....:     print id(row)
       .....:     
    3065415660
    3065415660
    3065415660
    3065415660
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
matrix = [[0 for row in range(4)] for col in range(4)]
```

Comment: Unused variables may be replaced by **_**

Comment: Of course, I was just trying to make it clearer by adding the 'row' and 'col' :-)

Answer (score -1):

Your code works ok, but it's not flexible one. So, if you want to create 5*5 martix you have explicitly add more line objects to matrix init code. So, using for + xrange generators looks more suitable.

Also, not sure about case of using this matrix - but be aware about using the **same** object (list) as matrix line. So, if you change it's element - it would be modified in all rows:

```
matrix[0][0] = 'new value'
print matrix

[['new value', 0, 0, 0], ['new value', 0, 0, 0], ['new value', 0, 0, 0], ['new value', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: It's not OK, because it does not do what user expects - see other answers