# Why does an operation on two identical lists end up in different results?

Tags: python, list, initialization, equality

I have a Python code, where I first define two lists, then I make them identical and do the same operation on them after they are identical - but the result is not the same:

```
test1 = [[[0],[0]]]*2
test2 = [[0]]*2

test2[0] = [[0],[0]]
test2[1] = [[0],[0]]

print 'They are identical?:',test1 == test2 # gives True

# Now that test1 == test2 do the same operation on test list 1 and 2:

test1[0][0] = 2
test2[0][0] = 2

print test1
print test2
```

This gives

```
[[2, [0]], [2, [0]]]   # test1
[[2, [0]], [[0], [0]]] # test2
```

Can somebody explain the difference to me?

Comment: they are not identical ... in one you have multiple copies of the same list so if you change one you change them all ... in the other each list is its own and independent of the others

Comment: but I do not understand why the line test1 == test2 gives True and when I print them, they are look the same? How can I tell that they are different??

Comment: @AnnaChristine Use `is` operator for checking object's identity. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230178/846892

Comment: you need to have an understanding of mutable datatypes and what the times operator does ... basically you just need to study python until you know ...or you can do `test[0] is test[1]` to check

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thank you, the use of IS instead of '==' is part of the really good answer given by val : ) Very helpful.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Answers as given by val actually make this website appreciated and amazing - it helps people incredibly who are no experts and have no time to 'study python until they now' as you suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is a list,

```
x * 2
```

Returns two times the *same* elements from the list.

As lists are passed by references, this means:

```
>>> A = 2 * [[0]]
>>> B = [[0], [0]]
```

Will actually not have the same structure: both `A[0]` and `A[1]` point to the *same* list, while `B[0]` and `B[1]` point to two different lists.

And indeed, if you try:

```
>>> A[0] == A[1]
True
>>> A[0] is A[1]
True
>>> A[0].append(1)
>>> A
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

While:

```
>>> B[0] == B[1]
True
>>> B[0] is B[1]
False
>>> B[0].append(1)
>>> B
[[0, 1], [0]]
```

Comment: @AnnaChristine: Good answer, except for the "pass by reference" bit.  See [How does Python referencing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9724802/208880) for some explanations about variables in Python.

Answer (score 2):

this command

```
test1 = [[[0],[0]]]*2
```

is equivalent of this 2:

```
a = [[0], [0]]
test1 = [a, a]
```

and then you assigning value to `test1[0][0]`, you are changing value of `a` list. Of course `test[1]` changes to, because it is same `a` list